# Value not being updated within the for loop

Tags: matlab

In the following code, the value of `gbest` is not updating with each iteration and showing `Infinity` as an outcome. Can anyone help me determine why?

```
fgbest=Inf; % Initialization of gbest

for j=1:Popsize

     % Generate Random Solution
     pop(:,j)=randi([500,2000],10,1);

     [obj]=objfn(pop,it);

     % Evaluation
     obj1(j,1) = obj(j,1);%

     % Update the Personal Best
     pbest(:,j) = pop(:,j);% pbest
     fpbest(j,1) =obj1(j,1);% objective function

     % Update Global Best
     test = fgbest>fpbest(j,1);
     if any(test)
        gbest = pbest(:,j);
     end

     gbest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because you initialized `fgbest` as Inf. As long as the value `fpbest(j,1)` remains smaller than Inf, the value of `gbest` will not be updated, because the `if` condition is not satisfied. Could you try initializing it with 0 or any other smaller value?

Comment: Actually the aim is to keep the obj value below the maximum possible value ie. infinity and later i want to update it towards the minimum possible value. but thank you for your comment :)

Comment: It's not clear since you don't provide definitions for your variables, but, why do you even need to use `any` at all here? Isn't `test` a single logical 0 or 1? If it's *not* it might explain your error, as `any` will not behave as you might expect for 2D matrices.